# How can I 'cycle' through list items when using classes in python pygame to change object colors?

Tags: python, pygame

I have drawn a caterpillar using `pygame.draw` and it's color is set as `self.color_scheme[0]` For example.

```
self.color_scheme = [red,yellow,purple]
...
...
pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, self.color_scheme[0], [x, y, 40, 45])
```

What I'm trying to enable is that when the user presses a key, lets say `s` then the color will change to `self.color_scheme[1]` or `self.color_scheme[2]`

Something along the lines of

```
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_s:
            #scroll through self.color_scheme or randomly select a color
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cycle:

```
self.color_scheme_idx = -1

if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_s:
        self.color_scheme_idx += 1
        pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, self.color_scheme[self.color_scheme_idx], [x, y, 40, 45])
```

To randomize:

```
import random

if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_s:
        pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, random.choice(self.color_scheme), [x, y, 40, 45])
```